# Normalization before clustering

Tags: python, cluster-analysis, normalization, k-means, categorical-data

Is it mandatory to normalize the data before clustering if we have categorical data which is converted to numerical values using dummies and label encoding? and if yes then which is the most appropriate normalization technique to use in this case?

Comment: This post suggests that categorical data should be one-hot encoded which would then not require any normalization: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/399430/does-categorical-variable-need-normalization-standardization

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to normalize the data for categorical values. Normalization/standardization of features is done to bring all features to a similar scale.

If you use k nearest neighbors, it only looks at similarities between your samples, so bigger/smaller relation does not affect it in this case.

Finally, normalization/standardization does not affect the ordering of values. So if x1 is larger then x2, after normalization or standardization they both would have potentially different values, but the relation between them would not change.

For clarification, refer the answers for this:
https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/399430/does-categorical-variable-need-normalization-standardization